# Netbeans console keep all lines

Tags: java, netbeans, console

I need to output multiple (over 10000) lines to console. It seems that the output has a max limit around 7000, i.e only the last 7000 are visible after running my application. Is there a configuration to keep all lines so that i can scroll to the top and see from first line to last line? It seems to be that also Intelij and Eclipse console output have also a max limit? Any way to change it, specially for Netbeans?

**Update:**

I am using Apache Netbeans 11.0 (with  Java 12 on a Windows 10 PC if that is important) Changing the History Size as suggested by @skomisa didn't help. I'll try to clean install Netbeans 12 and see if it is solve my issue.

Comment: I tested with NetBeans 12.2 and did not hit your ~7,000 line limit. I wrote over 50,000 lines to the output window (using `System.out.println`), with each line containing over 100 characters. I did not hit a limit.

Comment: Please add a tag to your question for the NetBeans version you are using (_netbeans-12_?).

Comment: [1] I just wrote a million `println()` lines to the terminal window within NetBeans, and every line was accessible afterwards. [2] Try increasing the value in **Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Terminal > History Size** to see if that helps. [3]  Please update your question to show your code and NetBeans version so that others can attempt to reproduce the problem if it persists.

Comment: For Eclipse, go to **Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Console**, then uncheck _Limit console output_, which causes the field _Console buffer size (characters)_ to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have NetBeans, but in Eclipse you can configure the Run Configuration to write the output to a file, where no such limit is in effect.

I would imagine that NetBeans and IntelliJ have similar options.

[image: Run Configuration]